# Dart,Flutter: get index value form its own position in list

Tags: flutter, dart

is there a simple way to get index value form its own position in list, like this:

```
List<Widget> widgets = [
    Text('${this.Myindex???}'),
    Text('${this.Myindex???}'),
    Text('${this.Myindex???}'),
]
```

so the return will be:

```
List<Widget> widgets = [
    Text('0'),
    Text('1'),
    Text('2'),
]
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexOf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would use a collection-`for` loop:

```dart
var widgets = <Widget>[
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) Text('$i'),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might help

```
var index = 0;

String getIndex(){
  index++;
  return (index-1).toString();
}

List<Widget> widgets = [
    Text(getIndex()),
    Text(getIndex()),
    Text(getIndex()),
]
```